# Identify this movie where a woman is backing away from a rat-like creature?

Tags: identify-this-movie

I *think* it's a common one - I've certainly seen it several times before. This movie has a short clip of a black and white film where a woman is seen (who may have locked herself in a laundry room - details are hazy) backing away from a furry mass with a tail, a bit like a rat/brain combination. It wiggles, she screams, and the clip ends.

Any ideas? The clip isn't scary at all, by the way, and I think the "outer" movie's a comedy.

Comment: Do you remember anything about the outer movie? Might help to identify that so we can see the clip itself, or look in the credits for information on the clip.

Comment: @Justin808: Well, it's the one I'm looking for :) It's a comedy that I've seen quite a few times, and I believe it's popular. The outer movie isn't in black and white, and it was definitely made before 2008 and *probably* after 1980.

Comment: Additional, probably unhelpful notes about the rat-thing: it's about the size of a loaf of bread and has no eyes or mouth or anything. Just a ball of fur with a tail.

Comment: Oh, and the outer movie is probably about a PG rating. I first saw it when I was 7-ish. I think.

Comment: Sorry i thought you were looking for the inner movie :)

Comment: Does the outer movie have a lot of sketches like "kentucky fried movie"? Or was a character in the outer movie watching tv when this clip came on?

Comment: @BamfTheNightAway: A character was watching TV when this clip came on. Or was watching the particular movie that this clip comes from.

Comment: How old are you now? What's the ethnic background of the person watching tv? What type of comedy is it (teen, romantic, stoner, etc)? Are they in a house/apartment? Nighttime or daytime? What time of year (xmas, halloween, summer) is the movie set in? Do you remember any of the actors/actresses?

Comment: @BamfTheNightAway: I'm 15 now. (7-ish - but I'm 100% sure it was made before 2008.) I don't remember where they are, or the time of day, or the time of year, or any actors or actresses. It might have been sci-fi/comedy though.

Comment: Since in the comments you have noted that @michael Stern's answer is the correct one, don't forget to mark it as "Accepted" by clicking the Checkmark next to his answer!

Comment: @TylerShads: It's not the correct one :) I gave it the bounty, but the film I'm looking for contains the one he found! (And I still haven't remembered it yet.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This clip appears in [It Came From Hollywood](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It_Came_from_Hollywood), as part of a montage of scenes of women being attacked by mobile brains. That was, I suppose, a trope in low-budget mid-20th-century horror/sci fi films.

The specific movie depicted may be [Fiend Without A Face](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiend_Without_a_Face).

> This intelligence soon begins to multiply its numbers by claiming even
> more local victims. These creatures later become visible while
> continuing to feed on the higher levels of power now being generated
> at the airbase. Their mutated "bodies" are revealed to be the missing,
> now enlarged brains and connected spinal cords removed from their
> victims; the spinal cords have become very flexible and have sprouted
> feelers. These mutations allow the creatures to move quickly and even
> to leap; each brain has also developed a pair of small eyes on
> extended eye stalks.
>
> The film climaxes with the visible creatures
> attacking an isolated house where most of the film's main characters
> have gathered to discuss the growing crisis. Having come armed, the
> defenders discover the creatures can be easily dispatched with
> well-aimed gun shots to their exposed brain-bodies.

Comment: THANK YOU! *It Came From Hollywood* is actually the inner movie, but I can probably remember it now! (So it's a clip within a movie within a movie. Heh.)

Answer (score 0):

Is it Terrorvision? http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0092074/

The characters watch several old black and white movies during the film. Its been a while since I saw it so I'm not sure if the scene you mentioned is definitely there but it could be worth a look.